# Linear trasnformation kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space. Let $T: V \to V$  be a linear transformation.

Prove that if $\text{Ker}\: T = \text{Ker}\: T^2$ then $\text{Im}\:T = \text{Im}\:T^2$.

How do I prove it?

Comment: One of the containments is true regardless of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. Let $y \in \text{Im }T^{2}$. Then there exists $v \in V$ such that $y = T^{2}v = Tu$ with $u = Tv$ and so we have $\text {Im }T^{2} \subset \text {Im }T$. It remains to use the hypothesis to show that the two sets have the same dimension, which follows from the hypothesis and the the following formula:

$\dim \ker T + \dim \text {Im } T = \dim \ker T^{2} + \dim \text{Im }  T^{2} $.